# Clearing Page Cache in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, outputcache

For my blog I am wanting to use the Output Cache to save a cached version of a perticular post for around 10 minutes, and thats fine...

```
<%@OutputCache Duration="600" VaryByParam="*" %>
```

However, if someone posts a comment, I want to clear the cache so that the page is refreshed and the comment can be seen.

How do I do this in ASP.Net C#?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I've found the answer I was looking for:

```
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/caching/CacheForever.aspx");
```

Comment: does anyone know if something like this is available for classic ASP?

Comment: I don't think caching was available in ASP, so no sorry.

Comment: This clears all the caches for every for every params for that page.

Comment: I'm using MVC 5.2.3, where should I write this code?

Comment: I am using a web user control for dynamic menus, I am using outputcache and want to remove cache on logout, I used your solution and passed my user control's path but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 41):

The above are fine if you know what pages you want to clear the cache for. In my instance (ASP.NET MVC) I referenced the same data from all over. Therefore, when I did a [save] I wanted to clear cache site wide. This is what worked for me: http://aspalliance.com/668

This is done in the context of an OnActionExecuting filter. It could just as easily be done by overriding OnActionExecuting in a BaseController or something.

```
HttpContextBase httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
httpContext.Response.AddCacheItemDependency("Pages");
```

Setup:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("Pages", DateTime.Now);
}
```

Minor Tweak:
I have a helper which adds "flash messages" (Error messages, success messages - "This item has been successfully saved", etc). In order to avoid the flash message from showing up on every subsequent GET, I had to invalidate after writing the flash message.

Clearing Cache:

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("Pages", DateTime.Now);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ir works only for entire page caching. It doesn't work for child actions. Any suggestions?

Comment: and.maz did you figure this out?

Comment: @and.maz In case you figured out how to do this for child actions, there's a bounty [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5126751/63733).

Comment: This did not work for me. This inability to clear elements of a cache seem like one enormous shortcoming in mvc

Comment: Probably, you can't clear the cache because you use @Html.Action() to render the partial view. You will have to use `OutputCacheAttribute.ChildActionCache = new MemoryCache("NewRandomStringNameToClearTheCache");` to clear the entire "child action cache" (for all child actions - It seems there is no better approach without using a library). http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/programmatically-clearing-0

Comment: @Kevin can you explain how to clear all cached pages of website after logout

Answer (score 6):

Using Response.AddCacheItemDependency to clear all outputcaches.

```
  public class Page : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string cacheKey = "cacheKey";
            object cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey];
            if (cache == null)
            {
              HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
            }

            Response.AddCacheItemDependency(cacheKey);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new SystemException(ex.Message);
        }

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }     
 }



  // Clear All OutPutCache Method    

    public void ClearAllOutPutCache()
    {
        string cacheKey = "cacheKey";
        HttpContext.Cache.Remove(cacheKey);
    }
```

This is also can be used in ASP.NET MVC's OutputCachedPage.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I'm looking for. There is only one thing you should change. HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(cacheKey);

Answer (score 3):

On the master page load event, please write the following:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

and in the logout button click:

```
Session.Abandon();
Session.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. You can specify a VaryByCustom attribute on the OutputCache item. The value of this is passed as a parameter to the GetVaryByCustomString method that you can implement in global.asax. The value returned by this method is used as an index into the cached items - if you return the number of comments on the page, for instance, each time a comment is added a new page will be cached.

The caveat to this is that this does not actually clear the cache. If a blog entry gets heavy comment usage, your cache could explode in size with this method.

Alternatively, you could implement the non-changeable bits of the page (the navigation, ads, the actual blog entry) as user controls and implement partial page caching on each of those user controls.

Answer (score 1):

If you change "*" to just the parameters the cache should vary on (PostID?) you can do something like this:

```
//add dependency
string key = "post.aspx?id=" + PostID.ToString();
Cache[key] = new object();
Response.AddCacheItemDependency(key);
```

and when someone adds a comment...

```
Cache.Remove(key);
```

I guess this would work even with VaryByParam *, since all requests would be tied to the same cache dependency.

Answer (score 1):

why not use the sqlcachedependency on the posts table?

[sqlcachedependency msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx)

This way your not implementing custom cache clearing code and simply refreshing the cache as the content changes in the db?

Answer (score -1):

`HttpRuntime.Close()` .. I try all method and this is the only that work for me

Comment: I would suspect that this is closing the ASP.NET application process on IIS. This seems a bit excessive, would probably clear all caches and would have significant performance problems on large websites.