# VB.net loading out of date webpages

Tags: vb.net

I use the following code to copy a certain line of text from the website listed.

```
    'Track A
    Dim TrackA As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/common/nat.html")
    Dim GaA As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = TrackA.GetResponse
    Dim WrA As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(GaA.GetResponseStream)
    Dim ContentStrA As String = WrA.ReadToEnd
    Dim StartIndexA As Integer = ContentStrA.IndexOf(vbLf & "A ") + 1
    Dim StrLengthA As Integer = ContentStrA.IndexOf(vbLf, StartIndexA) - StartIndexA
```

However when I open the link in a tab in VB, it shows a version of the site from a few days ago, how do I prevent this from happening as I need the current version of the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the [Cache Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.cachepolicy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` object, so that you're not getting cached results.

Alternatively, you can [clear the cache for your URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11061136/102937).