# Why the removed file on the host, can be download by my downloader application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, iis, webserver

I am creating a `downloader application`. My codes work very well but i have a problem as bellow:

- I put a file in a place on the host by FTP. It can be accessible by a link like this:

> example.com/box/music.mp3

- First, i run my `downloader` and it try to download the **music.mp3** and it can do it completely.
- Now, i rename the **music.mp3** to **music11111.mp3** on the host by a FTP application.
- Then, i run my `downloader` again and it try to download the **music.mp3** and **it can**!!!

Why my `downloader` can download the removed or renamed file on the host???

**I can download it by firefox even!**

I used the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532211/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-httpwebrequest#11061136) in my application to prevent cache but it didn't help me.

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("WinInet.dll", PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void DeleteUrlCacheEntry(string url);
}
```

I think this is a effect by web server, such as cache or.... is it? any idea...?

Is there a way to prevent download a cached file without any code on the web server?

If i should write some codes on the host please guide me by a link or instruction, my host is a `Windows Server` and it use `IIS` and my Website has been written by `ASP.NET MVC`.