# How I can close a httpRequest and a HttpSessionState?

Tags: c#, httprequest

I have a problem with the login of a web page that I am working. when I log in the page, I save the information in the `HttpRequest` and `HttpSessionState`. But when I logoff and I create a new user for the page, this information is still stored in these parameters. 
How I can close a `httpRequest` and  a `HttpSessionState`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Web Forms? What Authentication method are you using? Typically, in Web Forms, in the event handler for the Logout button, you would sign-out from Forms Authentication and the Session.

```
Session.RemoveAll();
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

Comment: Yes, I use the Form Autentication and I didn´t have insert the Session.RemoveAll(). But the Clean method also works. Thanks for yours help.

Answer (score 0):

You can close a HttpSessionState using the following:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.clear(v=vs.110).aspx

And here is another stack question regarding the httpRequest

[How to clear the cache of HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532211/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-httpwebrequest)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The clean method worked . But I don't understand something in the HttpRequest . HttpRequest is the same as the HttpWebRequest?