# How does HttpWebRequest cache responses? And why recycling app pool did not work?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, httpwebrequest, system.net.httpwebrequest

What is the way of `HttpWebRequest` cache works?

I tried recycling the app pool on IIS in which my web application is hosted but I was still getting cached responses.

So cache entries are not stored in memory? How exactly it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache is stored on disk.

`HttpWebRequest` uses the `WinINet` caching which is the underlying caching mechanism for Internet explorer. Files are stored in Temporary Internet Files folder which the same location where IE stores temp content. **So, if you delete the Temporary Internet files, the cache would be cleared.**

From [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532211/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-httpwebrequest) answer from StackOverflow

> HttpWebRequest uses System.Net.Cache.RequestCache for caching. This is
>   an abstract class; the actual implementation in the Microsoft CLR is
>   Microsoft.Win32.WinInetCache which, as the name implies, uses the
>   WinInet functions for caching.

Another good article [here](http://blog.technovert.com/2013/01/31/httpclient-caching/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very good article also, helped me a lot to understand what is going on.