# How to "invalidate" portions of ASP.NET MVC output cache?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

Is there a way to programmatically invalidate portions of the ASP.NET MVC output cache?  What I would like to be able to do is, if a user posts data that changes what would be returned from a cached action, be able to invalidate that cached data.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200616/abort-outputcache-duration-programatically-in-asp-net-mvc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167890/how-to-programmatically-clear-outputcache-for-controller-action-method

Answer (score 39):

One way is to use the method :

```
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/Home/About");
```

Another way is described here : http://aspalliance.com/668

I think you could implement the second method by using a method level attribute for every action that you want and just add to it the string representing the key. That's if I understood your question.

**Edit:** Yes the asp.net mvc OutputCache is just a wrapper .

If you're using `varyByParam="none"` then you just invalidate `"/Statistics"` - that's if `<id1>/<id2>` are querystring values. This will invalidate all versions of the page.

I did a quick test and if you add `varyByParam="id1"` and then create multiple versions of the page - if you say invalidate invalidate `"/Statistics/id1"` it will invalidate just that version. But you should do further tests.

Comment: is the MVC OutputCache attribute just a wrapper around the usual ASP.NET output caching?  So, let's say I wanted to invalidate the results for an action called "/Statistics/<id1>/<id2>" I would just call HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/Statistics/<id1>/<id2>")?  FWIW, The "VaryByParams" property of the attribute is "None."  Am I using that property correctly?

Comment: @Matthew Belk: Did you use this technique in the end?  Did invalidation of a cache item by param work as expected? thanks.

Comment: I would recommend using MvcDonutCaching, more info available here http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3

Comment: Link to ASP Alliance is broken

Answer (score 1):

I did some test on caching. This is what I found:

You have to clear the cache for every route that lead to your action.
If you have 3 routes that lead to the exact same action in your controller, you will have one cache for each route.

Let's say, I have this route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "config1",
                url: "c/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "myController", action = "myAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Defaultuser",
                url: "u/{user}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Accueil", action = "Index", user = 0, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Accueil", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Then, these 3 routes lead to `myAction` in `myController` with the param `myParam`:

1. http://example.com/c/myParam
2. http://example.com/myController/myAction/myParam
3. http://example.com/u/0/myController/myAction/myParam

If my action is as follow

```
public class SiteController : ControllerCommon
    {

        [OutputCache(Duration = 86400, VaryByParam = "id")]
        public ActionResult Cabinet(string id)
        {
             return View();
}
}
```

I will have one cache for each route (in this case 3). Therefore, I will have to invalidate every route.

Like this

```
private void InvalidateCache(string id)
        {
            var urlToRemove = Url.Action("myAction", "myController", new { id});
            //this will always clear the cache as the route config will create the path
            Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(urlToRemove);
            Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(string.Format("/myController/myAction/{0}", id));
            Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(string.Format("/u/0/myController/myAction/{0}", id));
        }
```