# Output cache for multi-tenant application, varying by hostname and culture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, culture, multi-tenant

I have a *multi-tenant application* in ASP.NET MVC. The instance of the application that will be served is function of the *hostname* alone (something along the lines of stackexchange, I suppose).

Each instance of the application might have a *different culture* setting (even "auto", to read the browser's language and try to use it), and will be *localized* accordingly.

In this situation, I'd like to do some **output caching** on some of my actions. So, my questions are:

1. What are the **possibilities to achieve output caching** of a multi-tenant ASP.NET MVC application, if the **output depends exclusively on the hostname** (ie, ignoring the localization requirement)?
2. Same as (1), but now considering that the **output depends on the culture settings** as well?
3. Same as (2), but considering that the **output might vary with parameters** that were passed to the action?

In this case, I'm considering that all the sites run from a single IIS website.

Comment: Are there multiple IIS website instances or do all websites run from a single website?

Comment: In this situation, all websites run from a single website.

Comment: Awesome question :) I have the exact same situation for a number of sites like this!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I've just figured out how to achieve this.

Simply use the `VaryByHeader` property, set to `"host"`. There are many possibilities to do so.

### Method 1

Use the `OutputCacheAttribute` passing all the needed configuration elements, including `VaryByHeader`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{  
    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "none", VaryByHeader = "host")]
    public ActionResult Index() { /* ... */ }
}
```

### Method 2.

Or you could set it to a profile on the Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- ... -->
  <system.web>
    <!-- ... -->
    <caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <clear/>
          <add name="Multitenant" 
               enabled="true"
               duration="3600"
               varyByHeader="host"
               varyByParam="none"/>
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then use it:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{  
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Multitenant")]
    public ActionResult Index() { /* ... */ }
}
```

### Method 3.

Or you can subclass the `OutputCacheAttribute` and use it:

```
public sealed class MultitenantOutputCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public MultitenantOutputCacheAttribute()
    {
        VaryByHeader = "host";
        VaryByParam = "none";
        Duration = 3600;
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{  
    [MultitenantOutputCache]
    public ActionResult Index() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: HA WIKID! I wish I can give more points for this answer ... totally Kick Ass dude. thank you sooooo much :)

Comment: Hi Bruno, I'm in the same situation as well. Thanks for your solution. Did you manage to find a way to easily clear cache per host? For example when a client updates his/her page...

Comment: @Cyril This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1169671/1175419) has info on clearing cache (if you choose server-side caching).

Comment: @RichC thanks, but I ended up with outputcaching on the filesystem. Works great and can easily be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In case people land on this page and are looking for the equivalent in asp.net 2.x. The attribute will look like this:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 30, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any, VaryByHeader = "host", VaryByQueryKeys = new string[] { "*" })]
```

And you will need the middleware added. You need [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching/) and this code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //stuff before...

    services.AddResponseCaching();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    //stuff after...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //stuff before...

    app.UseResponseCaching();

    //stuff after...
}
```

[More details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-2.1)