# Conditionally add OutputCache Directive

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I'm using the OutputCache directive in my aspx pages.  I would like to add it or remove it based on the environment.  For example, have the directive for production, but not development environments.

An if statement on the page doesn't seem to work:

```
<% if (someCondition) { %>
  <%@ OutputCache Location="Any" Duration="1800" VaryByParam="None" %>
<% } %>
```

Is there a way to remove (or add) a directive in the code behind?  What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work? describe the error you get

Comment: Have you tried `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every OutputCache attribute can be handled programmatically as shown here: [How to cache in ASP.NET by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323290)

**Is there a way to remove (or add) a directive in the code behind?**

Not that I have seen so far but not excluding the possibility. Nevertheless you would not have to as you have *Response.Cache* at your disposal for your scenario which gives you the whole ten yards to play with.

Although if you are using ASP.NET MVC, then you can use it as attributes as shown here:
[OutputCacheAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx) ([OutputCache(CacheProfile = "MyProfile", Duration = 10)]).
There is a stackoverflow example as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167890/how-to-programmatically-clear-outputcache-for-controller-action-method).

**What's the best way to accomplish this?**

Using *Response.Cache*. Check the code below.

```
using System.Web;

//......
//......
//......

if (someCondition) 
{
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public); //Location="Any"
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1800)); //Duration="1800"
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true); 
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  Not using ASP.NET MVC, but thanks for the extra info.

Comment: This isn't a correct answer, as the calls shown merely set headers in the response, i.e. tell the browser how to implement client-side caching. This is not a match for all of the functionality exposed by the OutputCache directive; for example, using HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache, one cannot programmatically set the duration of the server-side cache.