# ASP.NET - Server control output cache

Tags: asp.net, .net, user-controls, outputcache

Is it possible to change the output cache and it's duration for specific control, from code-behind?

I mean, let's say I have control `News.ascx` that has:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByCustom="language" %>
```

Now I want to write somewhere some code, that will decide dynamically if use output cache and what will be the duration of that cache. Is it possible?

I thought, that I will able to use custom `OutputCacheProvider` that described on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94803/ASP-NET-Output-Cache-Provider), but I can't find a way how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it see details here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323290

Use response.cache as

```
if (x==y) 
{
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);   
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(6700)); 
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true); 
}
```

See a similar question [Conditionally add OutputCache Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903081/conditionally-add-outputcache-directive)

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure it will work. If I will use HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache, I think it will cache the whole output for the page, but I trying to manipulate cache just for specific controls on page and not whole page. The page has many elements that can not be cached.