# MVC3 clearing cached actionResult from Controller issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a very data intensive operation in my MVC3 application. To get some performance gains, I have cached the result as follows:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=60,VaryByParam="none")]
    public ActionResult Index(string server, string database)
{ //get+display a list of objects
}
```

This works well. But I want to clear the cache if certain actions happen like an `Edit` or `Create`. To clear the cache I am doing this

```
var urlToRemove = Url.Action("HtmlOutputMethod", "Controller");
Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(urlToRemove);
```

Following: [How to programmatically clear outputcache for controller action method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167890/how-to-programmatically-clear-outputcache-for-controller-action-method)

**BUT** when I try to cache the Action on the Server so that the cache deletion actually works like this:

```
[OutputCache(Location="Server", Duration=60,VaryByParam="none")]
    public ActionResult Index(string server, string database)
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation'

Is this deprecated in MVC3 or am I missing an assembly? I see this used all over the place but it won't compile on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says use OutputCacheLocation:

```
[OutputCache(Location=OutputCacheLocation.Server, Duration=60,VaryByParam="none")]
public ActionResult Index(string server, string database)
```

And at usings add:

```
using System.Web.UI;
```

Comment: that's it. I was missing the `System.Web.UI` reference. thanks