# Reset a PartialViewResult set with OutputCache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I reset/update/refresh a PartialViewResult which is cached (OutputCache) in ASP.NET MVC?

I want to perform this action through a ActionLink.

I've used this code in a ActionResult:

```
OutputCacheAttribute.ChildActionCache = new MemoryCache("CachedTable");
```

but it resets all my cached partial views.

Comment: I think this might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167890/how-to-programmatically-clear-outputcache-for-controller-action-method

Comment: I found an answer from this article: [Donut Output Caching in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3)