# Orchard - How to remove cache from a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

Using Orchard 1.7.1 CMS. I am creating a project 'Football' I am running the program and using a console app 'Boots' to access a controller on the football project and download a list of footballs. However it seems to cache the list. So if I edit the football list in the UI, or the db table and re run the Boots app. It downloads the old list.

In the dashboard I have tried to remove the cache

```
~/Brands/*
```

brands being the name of the controller. but this is not working, any ideas?

Comment: please post code for method of downloading a _list of footballs_ code. [Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167890/how-to-programmatically-clear-outputcache-for-controller-action-method)

Answer (score 1):

Iv found that adding `[Themed, OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]` above the action, will remove any cache