# Are cached URLs stored somewhere ? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

When the `OutputCacheAttriute` caches the result of an action is the url of the corresponding action stored somewhere ? I mean At some point in my application I am required to remove the cached content corresponding to some url(s) (there may be many). I need to remove them all. I'm using `Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem()` method for removing cached item. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That would not help. I need to programaticly erase cache. the code suggesting in your link won't help me.

Comment: Seems like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1169671/254973) could be helpful.