# Clear outputcache in ASP.net MVC 5 stored at client location

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a beginner in ASP.Net MVC 5. And I have applied caching in certain controller actions. Now I want an action to clear the client cache. How to achieve it.
Here is what I have now:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 10800, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client)]
public PartialViewResult Temp()
{
    return PartialView("Index", data);
}
```

Link I looked:
[ClearCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167890/how-to-programmatically-clear-outputcache-for-controller-action-method)

It has a solution which tells to use:  `Response.Cache.SetNoStore`

But it will tell client to never cache right? I am lost here. Please guide me. Under certain scenario only I want the cache to get cleared. In other scenarios caching should take place as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `meta` tag in your layout page (in html head):

```
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

and also add `golbal.asax.cs`:

```
 protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
     }
```