# Web.config caching and .NET caching

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I wanted to know if the `web.config` caching section is the same cache used by the MVC `HttpRuntime.Cache`.

If they are, is there any way to use them separately ? I want to have a **10 minutes** cache for my pages ( routes ) and a **1 hour** cache for my static content: html, css, js, etc.

This is my .NET cache:

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(
    key               : cacheKey,
    value             : clone,
    dependencies      : null,
    absoluteExpiration: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes( 10 ),
    slidingExpiration : Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
    priority          : CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
    onRemoveCallback  : null
);
```

This is how i use the web.config cache:

```
[OutputCache( CacheProfile = "Cache1H" )]
```

This is my web.config cache:

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
        <outputCacheSettings>
            <outputCacheProfiles>
                <add name="Cache1H" duration="3600" varyByParam="none" noStore="true" location="Client" />
            </outputCacheProfiles>
        </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
</system.web>
```

**EDIT**

How could i reset or expire the HttpRuntime cache from another application ? Let's say i have a website and i want do reset it at my admin so the website would update the cache and get the new information.

Answer (score 2):

Both are different caching types which can be used in MVC.

Output caching can be use to cache the complete page including data either on client or server side. Checkout http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs for more details

The other type caching is Memory caching HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert where you can cache the data using key and value pairs for certain period of time.Checkout memory caching details at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But one won't interfere with the other right ? They are different caches ?

Comment: Both are different cache. It depends on how exactly you are using both the cache. If you just want to cache the data you can use Memory caching and if you want to cache the entire page on client side or server side then use output caching.

Comment: I'm using them as i explained in my question, would i be able to reset the HttpRuntime cache from another application ?

Comment: Yes you would be able to reset the HttpRuntime cache from another application.  There are various ways to clear cache refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452722/clear-asp-net-cache-from-outside-of-application-not-using-source-code

Comment: That didn't really work, i tried to remove the cache created at my site that runs on MVC from my admin area that is using .NET and cache wasn't removed. I used HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove( cacheKey );