# How to remove OutputCache on ChildAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

I am trying to take advantage of the donut caching features in .Net MVC 3.  For my Home page, in my home controller, I have:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[ChildActionOnly]
[OutputCache(Duration=3600)]
public ActionResult IndexMain()
{
    return PartialView(ViewModelRepository.GetIndexViewModel());
}
```

I my view, I have:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("IndexMain");%>
```

This all works fine.  However, when the data changes, I run:

```
var urlToRemove = Url.Action("IndexMain", "Home");
Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(urlToRemove);
```

The RemoveOutputCacheItem executes without an error, but the ChildAction cache is not invalidated.  Is there a way to programmatically remove a cache item from a ChildAction?

Comment: A couple more links: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7530265/63733, http://thenullreference.com/blog/fixing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-outputcacheattribute-for-partial-views-to-honor-some-web-config-settings/, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7117242/63733

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using the VaryBy properties such as [VaryByParam or VaryByCustom](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308375)

Comment: Looks like this is the only way to go without using a full-blown reimplementation.

Answer (score 2):

There's a NuGet package to address this specific problem.  This explains the problem and their solution:

http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3