# ASP.NET MVC. How to clear values cached by [OutputCacheAttribute]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I use [OutputCacheAttribute] to cache some actions. Everything works fine. Let's say I set its Duration property to 1 hour. But I want to be able to clear cached values. Is it possible?

Comment: This has been asked and answered already, see 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585/clearing-page-cache-in-asp-net

Comment: The question you referred to page caching. It doesn't work for child actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at [OutputCacheAttribute] source code, it seems that the only possible solution is to implement a new class derived from MemoryCache and set it OutputCacheAttribute.ChildActionCache property. This class will be use some custom prefix for all cached keys, so I'll be quite easy to find them (and then remove from cache).