# It is possible to know the OutputCache size in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

I read this article: [How to remove OutputCache on ChildAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126751/how-to-remove-outputcache-on-childaction) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

I've applied `OutputCache` attribute on some actions which contain a lot of data. I want to know how much (the size) has been occupied in memory.

Can you show me how to see the size in **C# code** ?

Because on MSDN they didn't mention about cache size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **"Memory Profilers"** for that.

```
.NET Memory Profiler
 ANTS Performace Profiler
```