# How to clear OutputCache in Mono MVC2 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, outputcache

AddCacheItemDependency is used to clear OutputCache in Mono Apache MVC2 application using code below.
This is described in  [Clearing Page Cache in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585/clearing-page-cache-in-asp-net)

In Mono, OutputCache is not cleared.
Looking into source code in GitHub shows that AddCacheItemDependency  is not implemented in Mono.
How to fix this so that OutputCache can cleared ?

Andrus.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddCacheItemDependency("Pages");
  return View();
}

public ActionResult Refresh()
{
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert( "Pages", DateTime.Now);
}
```

in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert( "Pages", DateTime.Now);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try remove output cache manually?

Like:

```
var urls = new List<string> {
                    Url.Action("Index", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" }))
            };
urls.ForEach(HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem);
```

Comment: This reqires knowing exact urls. Url can also contain query string parameters wchic can vary. How to get all urls which are in cache ?