# How to clear cached action [OutputCacheAttribute] when database change in Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I have a partialView, containing a dropdownlist which filled by data from database. I want to cache this partialview due to rare change data. So I add [outputcache] attribute to action to cache action but when data in database change, I can not update cached data.

First I tried to remove cache for this action like this post :

> [Clearing Page Cache in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585/clearing-page-cache-in-asp-net)

But nothing happened and it showed old data. Then I Tried to Use SqlCacheDependency, but i find out that OutputCacheAttribute can not used for child actions.

I don't know how to handle this. Can any one help me.
Thank you in advance